# execute jar error could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, jar

sorry for another "could not find or load main class" question.

I'm new to Java. I searched for a while but couldn't find the reason.

My project is a very simple one created with `maven`.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=mycompany -DartifactId=faker -DinteractiveMode=false
```

pom.xml(default, not change)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>faker</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>faker</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and source code(default, not change)

```
package mycompany;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

I build jar file with `jar` command.

```
~$ jar cvfm MyCompany.jar manifest.txt  src/main/java/mycompany/App.java
# added manifest
# adding: src/main/java/mycompany/App.java(in = 705) (out= 352)(deflated 50%)
```

manifest.txt

```
~$ cat manifest.txt 
Main-Class: mycompany.App
# (has an empty new line here)
```

but whenever I executed it, it give me following error:

```
~$ java -jar MyCompany.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class mycompany.App
```

Where is wrong ?

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
Apache Maven 3.5.2
```

Thanks @ohlec and @Kayaman, to be more specific, here's the way to solve it.

```
# get App.class
~$ cd src/main/java/mycompany/ && javac App.java
# back to faker folder
~$ jar cvfm MyCompany.jar manifest.txt  -C src/main/java mycompany/App.class
~$ java -jar MyCompany.jar
# Hello World!
```

Comment: `App.java` is the source file. You're going to have to compile it before you jar it.

Comment: Also, this could be built with maven since maven is already being used.

Comment: @PaulZepernick, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jar should have a directory structure that mirrors the package structure; in your case, `src/main/java` is included, although that is not a package prefix. Use `-C` to specify the root directory:

```
jar cvfm MyCompany.jar manifest.txt  -C target mycompany/App.class
```

*Edit:* Also, as Kayaman pointed out, you need to include the `.class` file, not the `.java` file.

Comment: Thanks @ohlec, it works! Another question, what do you mean by "is not a package prefix". In this case what is a package prefix for "mycompany" ?

Comment: Why would you build a jar by hand if maven does it - just say `mvn package`

Comment: @mCY No, `src/main/java` is just where the source files are stored. `mycompany` is your package.